# Detect application re-opening?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to detect when a user double clicks on my application (in the finder) if it's already open? I need to detect this since my app is running hidden and only if the user "re-opens" it should it show a user interface.

Is there some sort of event / notification posted to the app when this happens?

Edit: I know that Mac OS X only allows one instance. I need to call a method on my current instance if the user *tries* to launch the app again.

**Edit: seems like - (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
 should do the trick.**

Comment: Normally cocoa application do not allow multiple instances to be running at the same time.

Comment: @ParagBafna I know, I simply need  to call a method on my current instance  if the user _tries_ to launch the app again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSApplication` Delegate `- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag`

> Sent by the application to the delegate prior to default behavior to
>   reopen (rapp) AppleEvents.

Answer (score -2):

Implement `applicationWillUnhide:` (from NSApplicationDelegate Protocol) at your application delegate. It should be called in case a user try to unhide an application.

Comment: Actually I was probably unclear, the app is running with only an icon in the system menu bar, but this too can be hidden via the app preferences. I presume this is different from hide / unhide via cmd+h or minimization. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Wesley, it sounds like you want your process to convert to a normal full app from a status item when the user tries to "open", presumably using TransformProcessType(). That's interesting -- were you successful? Any gotchas?

Answer (score -2):

Implement `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your App delegate.